# Is a red arrow equivalent to a red light?

Tags: traffic

Scenario: A traffic light with a standard red yellow green array, and a second red yellow green ARROW array. Example:

[image]

In the picture, the green arrow is on, but the red light is on, meaning you may turn left, but not go straight (presumably because the green arrow is on for the opposing traffic as well).

But it will also occur that the green light will be on, but the red arrow will be on. I've been in plenty of situations like that where there is no oncoming traffic.

Now, I've had a former judge in NY traffic court tell me that in that scenario, the red arrow is NOT the same as a red light, it's a sign that *you do not have the right of way*. If the main light is green, *and there is no oncoming traffic*, and you may turn safely, you are allowed to turn left.

Is that correct?

Comment: This will depend on the jurisdiction, of course. Did you want an answer for New York?

Comment: Not that logic is always at play in traffic design, but if you were able to turn on the red arrow, then there should really be a single traffic light for the turning lane which is red-yellow-green-green arrow. You get green+green arrow when you have the right of way, and just green when you're allowed to turn but have to yield. If the intent is to allow you to turn while yielding the right of way, a red arrow is a terrible way to indicate that, so I wouldn't expect that to be the case.

Comment: @NuclearWang in most US jurisdictions, right turns are allowed on a red light after coming to a complete stop and determining that the way is clear, just as if it were a stop sign.  This is also true for left turns if both roads have one-way traffic.  A green arrow would imply to drivers that there is no competing traffic to which they could possibly need to yield, so a better indication for this state would actually be a flashing red arrow, since a flashing red stoplight is equivalent to a stop sign.

Comment: In CA red-left + green-ahead = no you cannot left turn.  The combination unlit-left + green ahead = standard left turn with oncoming traffic has right of way etc.

Comment: @phoog I've never seen a traffic light that normally sequences between flashing red and solid red, or vice versa. I'm not sure they exist, as it wouldn't be possible to immediately tell when the light changes. A flashing red arrow would require left-turners to stop, which isn't the same as a green light with an unlit arrow that requires drivers to yield, but not stop. Your proposed solution isn't equivalent to what it's replacing.

Comment: @NuclearWang it should be green arrow, yellow arrow, flashing red arrow, or green circle, yellow circle, red circle plus flashing red arrow.  It's not my idea; I read about it on a traffic engineering site a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 3):

There is a national standard that requires states to treat traffic control signals in a consistent manner.

The Manual on [Uniform Traffic Control Devices for Streets and Highways](https://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov) defines nationwide standards for all roads open to public travel. States were required to adopt this standard as their legal State standard by 2012 or have in place a State standard that is in substantial conformance with the National Manual.

In [this manual](https://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/pdfs/2009r1r2/mutcd09r1r2editionhl.pdf) you can find the standards for all traffic control devices, how they're to be placed and their meaning.

Section 4D.04 Meaning of Vehicular Signal Indications, section 3C, describes what **CIRCULAR RED** and **RED ARROW** are meant to indicate (the bottom of page 451):

> Vehicular traffic facing a steady RED ARROW signal indication shall not enter the intersection to make the movement indicated by the arrow and, unless entering the intersection to make another movement permitted by another signal indication, shall stop at a clearly marked
>   stop line; but if there is no stop line, before entering the crosswalk on the near side of the intersection; or if there is no crosswalk, then before entering the intersection; and shall remain stopped until a signal indication or other traffic control device permitting the movement indicated by such RED ARROW is displayed.
>
> When a traffic control device is in place permitting a turn on a
>   steady RED ARROW signal indication, vehicular traffic facing a steady
>   RED ARROW signal indication is permitted to enter the intersection to
>   make the movement indicated by the arrow signal indication, after
>   stopping. The right to proceed with the turn shall be limited to the
>   direction indicated by the arrow and shall be subject to the rules
>   applicable after making a stop at a STOP sign.

Later in the same document, page 453, the language is more direct and indicates that turning shall not be permitted when facing a **RED ARROW** signal indication except as outlined above where other devices permit the movement:

> A steady **RED ARROW** signal indication shall be displayed when it is intended to prohibit traffic, except by a pedestrian signal head, from entering the intersection or other controlled area to make the indicated turn. Except as described in Item C.2. in Paragraph 3 of Section 4D.04 [the quoted text provided above], turning on a steady **RED ARROW** signal indication shall not be permitted.

Unless there are other traffic control devices (signs) allowing it, one may not enter an intersection when facing a red arrow. Of course, someone authorized to direct traffic can override the traffic control devices.

You can examine the [standards adoption practice of the various states](https://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/resources/state_info/index.htm) to see how any particular state has implemented the standard. New York, in particular, has adopted the national standard along with a State supplement. As an example supplement, New York's supplement for "**Application of Steady Signal Indications**" deals with protected U-turn movements where right turn on red is permitted by inserting the following language:

> If a protected U-turn movement is provided, and right turns on red are
>   allowed from the conflicting approach from the left, a RIGHT TURN ON
>   RED MUST YIELD TO U-TURN (R10-30) sign (see Section 2B.54) may be used
>   to advise road users making the right turn on red of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on local law. Normally, turn signals are specific to turn lanes, and your green light would be for the non-turning traffic. FWIW, it is NOT legal to turn on a red arrow in Maryland unless there's also a sign saying you can.

> Vehicular traffic facing a steady RED ARROW signal indication shall not enter the intersection to make the movement indicated by the arrow and, unless entering the intersection to make another movement permitted by another signal indication, shall stop at a clearly marked stop line; but if there is no stop line, before entering the crosswalk on the near side of the intersection; or if there is no crosswalk, then before entering the intersection; and shall remain stopped until a signal indication or other traffic control device permitting the movement indicated by such RED ARROW is displayed.When a traffic control device is in place permitting a turn on a steady RED ARROW signal indication, vehicular traffic facing a steady RED ARROW signal indication is permitted to enter the intersection to make the movement indicated by the arrow signal indication, after stopping. The right to proceed with the turn shall be limited to the direction indicated by the arrow and shall be subject to the rules applicable after making a stop at a STOP sign.

https://www.roads.maryland.gov/mmutcd/2011_Chapters_04D.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is location specific.

In Wisconsin you may not proceed when the arrow is red, even if the "straight ahead" light is green. If you are allowed to proceed but must yield to oncoming traffic, the light will blink yellow.

This is outlined in Wisconsin [346.37 (1)(d) and (e)](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/statutes/statutes/346/VI/37):

> #### (d) Green arrow.
>
> 1. Vehicular traffic facing a green arrow signal may enter the intersection to make the movement indicated by the arrow but shall yield the right-of-way to pedestrians, personal delivery devices, bicyclists, and riders of electric personal assistive mobility devices lawfully within a crosswalk and to other traffic lawfully using the intersection. Vehicular traffic facing a left turn arrow may make a U-turn unless a sign prohibits U-turns. When the green arrow signal indicates a right or left turn traffic shall cautiously enter the intersection.
> 2. No pedestrian, bicyclist, or rider of electric personal assistive mobility device facing such signal may enter, and no personal delivery device operator may allow a personal delivery device facing such signal to enter, the roadway unless he or she can do so safely and without interfering with any vehicular traffic.
>
> #### (e) Flashing yellow arrow.
>
> 1. Vehicular traffic facing a flashing yellow arrow signal may cautiously enter the intersection to make the movement indicated by the arrow but shall yield the right-of-way to pedestrians, personal delivery devices, bicyclists, and riders of electric personal assistive mobility devices lawfully within a crosswalk and to other traffic lawfully using the intersection. Vehicular traffic facing a left turn arrow may make a U-turn unless a sign prohibits U-turns.
> 2. No pedestrian, bicyclist, or rider of an electric personal assistive mobility device facing such signal may enter, and no personal delivery device operator may allow a personal delivery device facing such signal to enter, the roadway unless he or she can do so safely and without interfering with any vehicular traffic.

The red light is outlined in section (c) of the same code:

> #### (c) Red.
>
> 1. Vehicular traffic facing a red signal shall stop before entering the crosswalk on the near side of an intersection, or if none, then before entering the intersection or at such other point as may be indicated by a clearly visible sign or pavement marking and shall remain standing until green or other signal permitting movement is shown.

A "red arrow" is the same as any other red light under Wisconsin statutes. [This is clarified more on the Wisconsin DOT page](https://wisconsindot.gov/Pages/safety/education/drv-behavior/red-lights.aspx).

**TLDR:**
In Wisconsin, proceeding on a red light would be illegal, even if the straight ahead signal is green.

Answer (score 0):

A solid red arrow is the equivalent of a red light for the specific turn lane aligned to that arrow.   In some jurisdictions there maybe a flashing Red Arrow which would be treated as a stop sign for the turn lane (proceed only after stopping and oncoming traffic has the right of way).  My understanding is that NYC does not permit any turns on red unless signs say otherwise (even Right on Red, which everywhere else in the U.S. such a turn is legal unless a sign says otherwise).